# Using gson to parse json to java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a json data into a java object, then post it to a .jsp to then turn it back into a json object so I can put it into a javascript array.

Here is an example of the data I want to parse:

```
"LoanList" = [ {"Loan" : "One","Lat" : "35.65365", "Lng" : "123.1331" , "Bal" : "4565" ,  "Address" : "Address 1" , "Delinquency" : "True')]
```

After reading about it, I decided to use gson to parse the data: After reading other questions about this topic, I wrote two classes.

**class1.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JSON1 {

    ArrayList<innerData> Loanlst;


    public ArrayList<innerData> getLoanlst() {
        return Loanlst;
    }
    public void setLoanlst(ArrayList<innerData> Loanlst) {
        this.Loanlst = Loanlst;
    }
}
```

**class2.java**

```
import java.math.*;

public class innerData {
public String loan;
public BigDecimal lat;
public BigDecimal lng;
public BigDecimal bal;
public String addrs;
public String delinq;

public String getLoan() {
    return loan;
}

public void setLoan(String loan){
    this.loan = loan;
}

public BigDecimal getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(BigDecimal lat){
    this.lat = lat;
}

public BigDecimal getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(BigDecimal lng){
    this.lng = lng;
}

public BigDecimal getBal() {
    return bal;
}

public void setBal(BigDecimal bal){
    this.bal = bal;
}

public String getAddrs() {
    return addrs;
}

public void setAddrs(String addrs){
    this.addrs = addrs;
}


public String getDelinq() {
    return delinq;
}

public void setDelinq(String delinq){
    this.delinq = delinq;
}
}
```

Here is where I am stuck, Where do I create my new Gson() to parse the data before I send it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your class you should be able to do something like:

```
InnerData obj = new InnerData(...);//fill in with data
Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

check an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson)

Tip: try creating a main class to run it separately.

Comment: Or, you know, a TestCase!  :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject=parser.parse("your string").getAsJsonObject();

also if it is a jsonArray ,change getAsJsonObject to getAsJsonArray

also jackson offers an easy to to parser string to json
you can search jackson apache